# Loop through Recordset rows and paste if true

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a recordset `rsDatabase` which is the output of a `SELECT * FROM` query, so I want to take this recordset and only paste rows when the value in a particular column for that row is true.

So it would be something like this:

```
xlRow = 1
Do While Not rsDatabase.EOF
   If rsDatabase(rsDatabaseCol).Value = "example" Then
   'Paste the row here
   xlRow = xlRow + 1
   End If
rsDatabase.MoveNext
Loop
```

But I can't work out what the syntax is for only pasting one row.

Comment: Does the condition  `rsDatabase(rsDatabaseCol).Value = "example"` work? And why is `rsDatabase.MoveNext` inside the condition?

Comment: Why not add a `Where`-clause to the `Select` and use `Range.CopyFromRecordset` ?

Comment: @FunThomas: Right, this is probably the better way to go. But the posted code just contains the mistake that the OP moves to the next record within the if condition. Strange that he does not get an endless loop unless the recordset only contains one record which fulfills the condition.

Comment: The OP also says "So it would be something like this" I guess meaning they haven't got it working yet so haven't spotted that mistake.  So, remove `Else` - no point it being there as there isn't an `Else`, put the `MoveNext` line after the `End If` and then `Sheet1.Cells(xlRow,1)=rsDatabase.Fields("MyField")` - or as @FunThomas said - add the `WHERE` clause to the `Select` statement or filter `rsDatabase` recordset and `CopyFromRecordSet`.

Comment: Apologies I didn't make it very clear. The code provided is purely to show the process of what I'm trying to achieve. I've edited to make better. I don't want to use a WHERE in my SQL because I execute the SQL multiple times for different variables, so I'd rather run the query once and then deal with the Recordset within VBA as it's more efficient.

Comment: What is the question then? Because the code above is correct if `rsDatabaseCol` is a valid column name. You only have to add a line like `cells(i,j) = rsDatbase(fieldname).value`. You could also use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/filter-and-recordcount-properties-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017) method of a recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment I would suggest to use the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/filter-and-recordcount-properties-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017) method of a recordset and then use [CopyFromRecordSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset). No loop is needed unless you want to add the column names at the top of table.

```
For i = 0 To rsDatabase.Fields.Count - 1
     Range("A1").Offset(0, i) = rsDatabase.Fields(i).Name
Next i
rsDatbase.Filter = rsDatabaseCol & " = 'example'"
rsDatabase.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't know there was a .Filter method for recordsets! If I want to apply multiple filters to a recordset in sequence, do I need to remove a previous filter or does a new filter remove the previous?

Comment: A new filter will remove the previous one and you can remove a filter with `rsDatbase.Filter = ""` or  `= adFilterNone`  But to be on the save side you could remove the filter first and then set the new one.